# Scroll ListView inside PageView from SingleChildScrollView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, layout, scroll, flutter-layout

I have a tab bar with a `PageView` inside each `TabBarView`. Each `PageView` has a `ListView` and when I scroll it, how can I scroll from the Scaffold's `SingleChildScrollView` rather than just scrolling the `ListView` inside the `TabBarView`?

Currently, the tab bar stays on the same position when I scroll the `TabBarView`, which looks terrible. How can I scroll individual `TabBarView` from `SingleChildScrollView`?

I tried tweaking with `physics`, but didn't turn out the way I wanted it to.

**IMAGE :**

[image]

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int currIndex = 0;
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController =
        TabController(vsync: this, length: 3, initialIndex: currIndex);

    _tabController.addListener(() {
      _handleTabSelection();
    });
  }

  void _handleTabSelection() {
    setState(() {
      currIndex = _tabController.index == null ? 0 : _tabController.index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: DefaultTabController(
          length: 3,
          initialIndex: 0,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          child: Container(
                              child: Text(
                            "HOME",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                          )),
                        ),
                        _buildTabBar(context),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: _buildTabBarView(
                      context,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  TabBarView _buildTabBarView(BuildContext context) {
    return TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: List.generate(
            3,
            (index) => Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 50,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Container(
                            height: 60,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            child: Center(child: Text("$index"))),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                )));
  }

  Widget _buildTabBar(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8),
      child: Container(
        height: 45,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: buildTabBarStyle(),
        child: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          isScrollable: false,
          tabs: List.generate(
              3,
              (index) => Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "$index",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  BoxDecoration buildTabBarStyle() {
    return BoxDecoration(
      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 248, 255),
      border: Border.all(
        width: 1,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: did you try "primary: false" property in ListView? It makes the ListView scroll as false and takes the scrolling of it's parent

Comment: I tried it. Didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a different approach to do it simply.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final TabController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
  }

  BoxDecoration buildTabBarStyle() {
    return BoxDecoration(
      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 248, 255),
      border: Border.all(
        width: 1,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
            SliverAppBar(
              snap: true,
              floating: true,
              pinned: false,
              toolbarHeight: 80,

              title: Text("Home"),
              // title: Search(),
              centerTitle: true,
              bottom: PreferredSize(
                preferredSize: Size(0.0, 48.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: buildTabBarStyle(),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: TabBar(
                    controller: controller,
                    isScrollable: true,
                    labelColor: Colors.green,
                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                    labelStyle:
                        TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16.0),
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(text: "1"),
                      Tab(text: "2"),
                      Tab(text: "3"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
          body: TabBarView(
            controller: controller,
            children: [
              ...List.generate(
                3,
                (t) => Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 50,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 60,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text("tab $t  index $index"),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ).toList(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```